# Trying to reproduce mirbase results locally with BLAST

Tags: blast

I am trying to reproduce locally on my computer what I get running mirbase on their website using BLAST. The 'search sequences' option is: mature miRNAs which I had downloaded on my computer and make it as a BLAST database with command:

`./makeblastdb -in /home/marianoavino/Downloads/mature.fa -dbtype 'nucl' -out /home/marianoavino/Downloads/mature`

then on mirbase I see they use an e-value of 10, which I leave locally.
On mirbase at the end of the analysis they give you these parameter setting:

Search parameters

Search algorithm:
    BLASTN 
Sequence database:
    mature 
Evalue cutoff:
    10 
Max alignments:
    100 
Word size:
    4 
Match score:
    +5 
Mismatch penalty:
    -4

and this is the command line I use on my computer for BLAST

`./blastn -db /home/marianoavino/Downloads/mature -evalue 10 -word_size 4 -query /home/marianoavino/Downloads/testinputblast.fasta -task "blastn" -out /home/marianoavino/Downloads/testBLast.out`

The results of the two analysis are different, with mirbase finding much more stuff than local BLAST.

Do you have any idea on which parameters I should use on local blast command line to match those listed mirbase parameters in order to get the same answer?

Answer (score 0):

There can be lots of reasons for different results including the version of blast you are using and which they used, parameters (like you said) and differences in the databases (remember, database size is used to calculate things like evalue, so you may end up with different results).

Exact replication of results may be difficult, but the question is *are the differences meaningful*? Just because an alignment has some evalue (which 10 is unusually high) does not mean it is meaningful. For a given sequence, if  searches are yielding different number of alignments, but **the same number of high quality alignments** (high bitscore, low evalue, full alignment between query and subject sequences), does it matter?

I would try and compare results to see where these differences are, then move forward